# Does Qt support the windows bluetooth API?

Tags: windows, qt, bluetooth, eclipse-cdt

Can anyone tell me whether or not Qt supports the windows Bluetooth API? 
If so could you please share some information on how to use it?

Comment: No, QT means Eclipse QT (CDT)

Comment: You're confusing a lot of things here. First of all it's Qt (small t). Eclipse CDT might your IDE, but has to the best of my knowledge nothing to do with Qt. And a quick Google learns that there is something like [QBluetooth](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/QBluetooth_-_A_Qt_bluetooth_library), but I have never used it, nor do I have any idea how useful it is.

Comment: @Bart: we are asking about the support of winodws bluetooth APIs in Qt

Comment: @Bart: Thanks for the link. I'm going through the link. But i have one doubt here, it is given that Qt for Symbian OS will the same QBluetooth library and steps given work for windows?

Answer (score 8):

The answer to this question has changed a bit since the last response was given.  Qt version 5.2 implemented a Bluetooth API for Linux/BlueZ and BlackBerry devices.  Qt 5.3 includes Bluetooth support for Android.  Linux devices can connect with RFCOMM or L2CAP protocols.  Android and Blackberry only have RFCOMM.

Bluetooth on Windows is still not supported, but that fact is hard to find.  Currently, if you create a [QBluetoothSocket](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qbluetoothsocket.html) on Windows and tell it to connect to an address, it fails silently even though there is a built-in error-reporting mechanism.  If you use the [QBluetoothLocalDevice](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qbluetoothlocaldevice.html) interface to retrieve devices, you get back an empty list.  Although the class documentations don't mention the fact, the [Bluetooth Overview](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtbluetooth-index.html) clarifies that

> Currently the API is supported on Android, BlackBerry 10 and Linux (Bluez 4.x).

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Qt 5.11, [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtbluetooth-index.html) says:

> Despite there not being a Win32 port yet, the WinRT backend is
>   automatically used if the win32 target platform supports the required
>   WinRT APIs. **Minimal requirement is Windows 10 version 1507** with
>   slightly improved service discovery since Windows 10 version 1607.
>   Therefore Windows 7 and 8.x targets are excluded.

[Bluetooth Chat Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-btchat-example.html) tested successfully using following setup:

> *Qt 5.11.1*
>
> Win10 Qt Kit MSVC2017 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

As January 2020 [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-index.html), Qt 5.14 officially supports "Classic Bluetooth" for win32 builds.

However, it doesn't seem complete, [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-overview.html) mentions a restriction about finding devices:

> ...it is only possible to find devices that have been previously paired through Windows Settings