# Alternatives to QtBluetooth on Windows?

Tags: windows, qt, bluetooth

I have two PCs, not connected with a cable and not in a network that need to communicate with each other. I'm doing two Qt apps and wanted to make the communication via Bluetooth. However, I found out that Qt does not support Bluetooth for Windows ([Does Qt support the windows bluetooth API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992333/does-qt-support-the-windows-bluetooth-api)). (It produces `qt.bluetooth: Dummy backend running. Qt Bluetooth module is non-functional.`)

So what other alternatives do I have to bluetooth to establish this connection?
Or how can I make QtBluetooth work? I am open for new suggestions.

The data to be transferred is a `QByteArray`.

I am running Windows 10 Pro and Qt 5.11.1.

**Edit:**
According to the new answer on [Does Qt support the windows bluetooth API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992333/does-qt-support-the-windows-bluetooth-api), `QtBluetooth` can indeed work on Windows. I have two windows devices with exactly the same windows and Qt version. On one of them the [Bluetooth chat example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-btchat-example.html) works perfectly, on the other one it still doesn't and I get the error message that `Qt Bluetooth module is non-functional`. Can someone tell me when and why this error appears?

I have also seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901662/qtbluetooth-not-functional-on-linux) but it doesn't help me, because it's linux-specific.

Comment: How about serial/USB connection?

Comment: @MohammadKanan The connection should not have a cable.

Comment: @Phiber I've never heard of it. I would prefer some easier option if it exists, but I'll definitely look into it. Thanks!

Comment: PC Bluetooth is usually integrated with WiFi ... use your wifi!!

Comment: I need an offline solution, and as I said the PCs do not share a network.. @MohammadKanan

Comment: @MohammadKanan and what do you mean with "PC Bluetooth is integrated with WiFi"?

Comment: Integrated hardware

Comment: Mariam what windows OS you have? and Qt kits?

Comment: It all in the question^^ 10 pro and 5.11.1 @MohammadKanan

Comment: Please check this again [Does Qt support the windows bluetooth API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992333/does-qt-support-the-windows-bluetooth-api)

Comment: This is exactly the question I linked above^^, so I do know it is not supported, this is why I am looking for alternatives.. @MohammadKanan

Comment: Nope, I updated the post with new answer there!

Comment: I tested `QBluetooth` on almost same as your env and it works ... check details

Comment: Oh great news! but then how do I make it work? I have updated my question. @MohammadKanan

Comment: You need to make sure Bluetooth on the other PC works first, try to find a resource on _How to establish Bluetooth link between 2 PCs_ ... ... debug the wrong PC and then try with Qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://forum.qt.io/topic/93752/qtbluetooth-on-windows-not-working) thread on the QtForum delivered the answer. It works when you switch to the MSVC compiler instead of the standard MinGW!

This is how you do it:

After installing Microsoft Visual Studio and having the MSVC package in Qt (see mentioned thread), you need to set the compiler for c++ by going to Tools>Options>Kits. There you choose the MSVC compiler and in "Compiler: C++:" you choose Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler.

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You "exactly the same windows" most likely aren't. What is the exact version? The most current Windows 10 version is 1803, and the minimum needed for fully functional Qt Bluetooth support is 1607.

Comment: Both are Windows 10 Pro Version 1709

Comment: Do they have the same bluetooth chipset and same driver versions for it?

Comment: yes the RFCOMM Bluetooth devices have the same version. I'm not sure where I find info about the chipset itself.

Comment: Look in the device manager and screenshot exact details of all  Bluetooth device driver as well as host driver files. It’s possible that they are not the same.

Comment: I already looked. The RFCOMM is exactly the same. The PAN Bluetooth is a different version.

Answer (score 0):

Now it seems that QT supports Bluetooth on Windows since [version 5.14](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-index.html)